# Query syntax error near "SELECT * FROM user"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495629/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-user)

I'm trying to use very simple SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio 2008, the exact query is:

```
SELECT * FROM User;
```

But it gives me error when I try to run this.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

This table exists and when I try to select any other table data with this statement (by replacing table name), I get all data as I want. Have anyone ideas how to repair it? Tried to google it, but didn't get answers.

Comment: SQL Server is decent about reporting this type of error (as opposed to MySQL) and gives hints here: "Incorrect syntax near the *keyword* 'User'".

Comment: A lot of times these errors can be avoided if you use plural names for tables. Since a table is a *set* of something, `Users` is better than `User` unless the intention is that the table will only ever hold one row. PS I'm not suggesting that is the solution, which is why I'm posting it as a comment.

Comment: Also it's great that we have six identical answers to this question. Anyone feel like withdrawing their answers to remove some noise?

Answer (score 9):

`User` is a keyword. You will need to use an escape character. Try

```
SELECT * FROM [User]
```

Comment: +1 You had the first answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

User is a reserved word. You should use brackets `[]`

```
SELECT * FROM [User]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [User];
```

Answer (score 2):

`User` is a reserved SQL keyword - try:

```
SELECT * FROM [User];
```

Answer (score 2):

user is a reserved keyword , can you change the tname

Answer (score 2):

"USER" is a SQL Server [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). You need to escape it:

```
SELECT * FROM [User];
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM "User";
```